# Change ItemFileWriteStore URL, get data and refresh Grid

Tags: dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid

I have an EnhancedGrid with ItemFileWriteStore. After calling startup() on the grid, I hide the same by using following code:

dojo.style(grid.domNode, 'display', 'none');

And then on the click of a button, I change the URL of store for this grid and try to refresh the store and show the grid by using following code:

```
store.save();
store.close();
store.url='AjaxPopulate.json?os_type='+dijit.byId('osType').get('value');
store.save();

store.fetch({query:{id: '*'}});
dojo.style(grid.domNode, 'display', '');
grid.store.close();
grid.setStore(store);
```

The above code works fine with Firefox and Chrome but not on IE8 and IE9. I simply get "Object Error" message in IE Developer tools console.

Pls. help me identify any issues with the above code.

Comment: there's not much to go on m8.. It can be either variable which is undefined at the time youre running the code; `store, grid, grid.store`. Its most likely a flaw in this: `dijit.byId('osType').get('value')`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Problem was that I had invalid JSON coming from server with one extra comma.

IE is very specific on these things.

Thanks everyone who viewed and tried to reply.

Comment: This is not an ans. You need to put this into comment section

Answer (score 1):

[Howto reload store](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/data/ItemFileReadStore.html#reloading-refreshing-itemfilereadstore-from-a-url-dojo-toolkit-1-4)

If using the 'data' property to populate store initially (via constructor), you should set `clearOnClose: true` as well.

Use of `.save()` is only for a ItemFileWriteStore that has some settings changed (isDirty) and needs to propagate these to server. That said, you dont need .save on a closed store (allthough url has changed, no fetch has been run and definately no items has changed).

Try the following code, you'd only need the `grid` component to do it as calling `.render()` on the grid will get it to reload it's data.

```
// save if dirty, otherwise we cannot close a store unless its reset
grid.store.save(); 
// close store, this should clear data
grid.store.close();
// set new URL
grid.store.url = '??';
// rerun fetch XHR
// reload grid data with new items (no need to setStore as its same object reused)
grid.store.fetch({query:{id: '*'}, onComplete: function() {grid.render}});
```